# Changing the Messages for required Fields in IntraWeb

Tags: delphi, intraweb

When setting the *Required* property of a IntraWeb control I get a nice little message box saying "Bezeichnung is a required field" if I leave it blank.

How can I change the Text of those messages?
(My application is in german language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found a hint in the atozed-Forums:

Copying IWResourceStrings.pas to my projects main folder and changing the needed strings to german works for me...

Maybe someone else will find this helpfull, too one day ;-)